# AWS Organizations permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm working with AWS. Specifically, I have an AWS Educate account with $ 100 free. When I go to the AWS Organizations service, I get a message saying: you don't have permission to access this resource. I've tried to add a full organization permission to the user, but I still have the same error.
Furthermore, I use the EMR cluster and the S3 bucket.
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Organizations is one of the services that are not supported in AWS Educate Starter Accounts. Please refer [to this document](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf) to learn about supported services.

If you want to use AWS Organizations, you can create a regular AWS account [here](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup#/start). You can have as many accounts as you want (in fact, that’s something that AWS Organization helps you with: Multi-account management).

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there no other service or similar way that would allow you to share instances for Amazon Educate?

Comment: sorry, I had not seen that you had edited the post. Yes, the problem is that I have the cluster emr, s3 bucket, and other services in the aws educate account. So should I set everything up again in the new aws account?

Comment: That is a functionality of the AWS Resource Access Manager, which depends on the AWS Organization. Maybe there is a workaround, but you probably should ask this on a separate question so that other people can find it and give you an answer.